# Saving SQL results to CSV having columns with HTML data

Tags: sql, csv

Is there a way to properly export HTML column data to CSV without breaking the CSV format?

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(CAST(content as NVarchar(4000)), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ' '), CHAR(44), ' ')
FROM documents
```

It works fine by stripping of any commas, carriage returns and line breaks.

Is there another proper way of doing this? For example a tool which exports to CSV without having to strip off the CSV breaking characters.

Comment: depending on the amount of data you have and the time it takes to execute? what is the issue your facing?

Comment: Give sample data with expected result??

Comment: I have no problem with the select and execution times. I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing it. For example a software tool I can use to easily do this without having to strip off any CSV breaking characters.